# Checkbox select all not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

My script worked very good until I add the (#check_all), my checkboxes don't work, but separately they work fine. I can't find the problem, help please.

my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".bt").click(function(){
    $(".select_box").hide('fast');
    if ($(this).next('.select_box').is(':visible')){
        $(this).next(".select_box").hide('fast');
    }
    else{
        $(this).next(".select_box").fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".select_box").hide();
});
$(".bt,.select_box").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  
    return false;                             
});

$('#check_all').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
}); 
});

</script>
```

Html

```
<a class="bt" href="#">[X]</a>
<div class="select_box" style="display:none;border:1px solid;">
    <input id="check_entite" type="checkbox" />(Select All)<br />
    <input type="checkbox" />1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" />2<br />
</div>
<br><br>
<a class="bt" href="#">[X]</a>
<div class="select_box" style="display:none;border:1px solid;">
    <input id="check_all" type="checkbox" />(Select All)<br />
    <input type="checkbox" />1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" />2<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Try to replace `attr` with `prop`.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this : [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bLt2k/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".bt").click(function (e) {
      $(".select_box").hide('fast');
      if ($(this).next('.select_box').is(':visible')) {
          $(this).next(".select_box").hide('fast');
      } else {
          $(this).next(".select_box").fadeIn('fast');
      }
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
  $(document).click(function (e) {
      $(".select_box").hide();
  });
  $('.select_box').click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('#check_all,#check_entite').click(function (e) {
      $(this).siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
      e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome..! Happy to be Helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('div').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is not the js, actually it's your logic too complex, you should re-organize it. try this or check the result [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zTd8t/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".bt").click(function(){
    $(".select_box").hide('fast');
    if ($(this).next('.select_box').is(':visible')){
        $(this).next(".select_box").hide('fast');
    }
    else{
        $(this).next(".select_box").fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".select_box").hide();
});
$(".bt,.select_box").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  
    return false;                             
});

$('#check_all').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('div:eq(0)').find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
      e.stopPropagation();  
    return false; 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with:

```
$(".bt,.select_box").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();  
    return false;                             
});
```

?

This is a working version: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLmW2/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".bt").click(function (e) {
        $(".select_box").hide('fast');
        if ($(this).next('.select_box').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).next(".select_box").hide('fast');
        } else {
            $(this).next(".select_box").fadeIn('fast');
        }
        return false;
    });
    $(document).click(function () {
        $(".select_box").hide();
    });

    $('.check_all').click(function () {
        var checked = ($(this).prop('checked'));
        $(this).parent('div').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
    });
});
```